# apache config VirtualDocumentRoot

Tags: apache, http-status-code-403, vhosts, error-log, mod-vhost-alias

I have this configuration in my `httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
<Directory "/Users/uername/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Sites">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Virtualhost *:80>
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/Users/uername/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Sites/_localhost"
    UseCanonicalName Off
</Virtualhost>
<Virtualhost *:80>
   VirtualDocumentRoot "/Users/uername/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Sites/%2"
   ServerName sites.dev
   ServerAlias www.*.dev
   ServerAlias www.*.dev.*.xip.io
   UseCanonicalName Off
</Virtualhost>
<Virtualhost *:80>
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/Users/uername/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Sites/%1"
    ServerName sites.dev
    ServerAlias *.dev
    ServerAlias *.dev.*.xip.io
    UseCanonicalName Off
</Virtualhost>
```

When I try to access my website, I get a 403 forbidden page.
When I look into the apache error log I see this:

```
[Sun Jun 26 12:09:12.310868 2016] [core:error] [pid 1272] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:50110] AH00035: access to /favicon.ico denied (filesystem path '/Users/username/Library/Mobile Documents') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path, referer: http://site.dev/
```

I don't fully understand why the path stops at `Mobile Documents`. All the folders do exist, I do have an `index.php` file in my root and nothing else explains the 403 error as well.

What am I missing here? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I solved the problem. Might not be the best way but it works, so if anyone has a better idea, please share.
My solution:
I changed the user and group apache was running from _www to my own username and group.
I used this solution:
https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/forbidden-403-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-username-on-this-server/

> Changing The Apache Web User
>
> One of the frustrations of using the Users/username/Sites folder is
>   the permissions issues with things like updates and authentication.
>
> This is because the default webserver user which runs `httpd` is known
>   as `_www`, which will not be the user in your local account. If your
>   machine is only in use by you and the webserver will run only under
>   your account then you can change the user.
>
> Change this back in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`
>
> [image: osx-yosemite-webserveruser]
>
> Just change it to your username and group, group will be staff and
>   restart Apache
>
> `sudo apachectl restart`